# The space of contractible loops of a finite dimensional $K(\pi,1)$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Let $X$ be a finite dimensional $K(\pi,1)$ manifold. Is it true that the space contractible loops of this manifold can be contracted to the space of constant loops on $X$? What if $X$ is a finite dimensional $CW$-complex?

I understand that the answer is positive if $X$ is a negatively curved manifold, since in this case there is a geometric argument.

Comment: This is correct and you will find it in a lot of literature on string topology. For example a stronger claim is made in Section 10.1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9911159.pdf. I'm sure you can find more detailed discussion in for example https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0511181.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I wonder how one proves this

Comment: There is a paper at https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.5617 on "The homotopy 2-type of a free loop space".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The statement is true for  a $K(\pi,1)$ but not true for other $X$. Finite dimensionality is not relevant.

Here's a sketch: let $X = K(\pi,1)$ and I will assume $X$ has the homotopy type of a CW complex. Let $\Omega_0 X$ be the space of contractible based loops in $X$.  It's easy to show that the homotopy groups of this space are trivial in every degree (in degree 0 by definition and in higher degrees since $X$ is a $K(\pi,1)$ space, using the fact that $\pi_j(\Omega_0X) = \pi_{j+1}(X)$ for $j >0$).

Let $L_0 X$ be the space of contractible unbased loops. Then the sequence
$$
\Omega_0 X \to L_0 X \to X
$$
is a fibration, where the second map is evaluation at the basepoint of the circle. Since the fiber has trivial homotopy groups, it follows that the map $L_0X \to X$ is a weak homotopy equivalence. It follows that the section $X\to L_0X$ given by the constant loops is also a weak homotopy equivalence. It's therefore a homotopy equivalence since the spaces in question have the homotopy type of a CW complex.

Comment: Dear John, thank you for the answer. I would like to ask one more thing. If you quotient $L_0X$ by $S^1$ and $X$ is $K(\pi,1)$, is it correct, that the resulting space is still homotopic to $X$?

Comment: I'm not sure. The action on the circle isn't free on $L_0X$. Taking the quotient by a non-free action isn't something I am able to identify. On the other hand, if we take the homotopy quotient, i.e., the Borel construction $ES^1 \times_{S^1} L_0X$, then one gets $\Bbb CP^\infty \times X$ up to homotopy.

Comment: Thanks John! Maybe then I'll ask a followup question. For a negatively curved manifold the quotient $L_0X/S^1$ is still homotopic to $X$ I believe (by a geometric argument).

Comment: And what is the geometric argument? Where can I find it?

Comment: I discovered it myself, so don't know a reference.  It works if the loops are smooth, but I guess this is a technicality. The idea is the following: if we have a smooth contractible map from a circle to a manifold of negative curvature, we can  uniquely contract it to a point. For example go to the universal cover, take a preimage of the circle and then find the "centre of mass" of the circle in the cover. The unique centre of mass is the point $m$ such that $\int_{S^1}d(m,\phi(x)) $  attains its minimum. Now, contract the circle to $m$ along geodesics. Finally, project it back to the manifold

Comment: I'm skeptical: I am a bit concerned that the point you are getting depends on the choice of lift to the universal cover.  Maybe what your argument shows is that the identity map of $L_0\tilde X/S^1$ factors through $\tilde X$ up to homotopy (where $\tilde X$ is the universal cover of $X$). So $L_0\tilde X/S^1$ is contractible (since $\tilde X$ is). The latter statement is true for all $K(\pi,1)$ spaces.